# text alignment with center environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am going to include some scripts (programming) in my document and I used `\texttt` to make them look different from the rest of the document and I am gonna move them to the center of page with `center` environment but I don't have any clue how to align them (like the alignment used for equations):

```
\begin{center}
\texttt{kmeans=: 3 :0 \\
Nr=: \$,smp \\
dis=: \%: @ +/"1(initial -"1/ grid)\^ 2 \\
index=:(|:dis) i."1 (,.<./"1 (|:dis)) \\
}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're not interested in a specific formatting of the scripts, then you can use the [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package to adjust the code location. Here's an example that indents the entire code by `2\parindent` (twice the standard `\parindent`) for a consistent horizontal alignment across scripts:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb
\fvset{xleftmargin=2\parindent}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Verbatim}
kmeans=: 3 :0
Nr=: $,smp
dis=: %: @ +/"1(initial -"1/ grid)^ 2
index=:(|:dis) i."1 (,.<./"1 (|:dis))
\end{Verbatim}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Using something like a `verbatim` environment (or `Verbatim` as provided by `fancyvrb`) removes the need to escape characters that are otherwise treated differently inside regular text. Moreover, the default font used it `\ttfamily` (this can be changed).

---

For actually centering the content, `fancyvrb` also allows you to capture the content in a box which provides the means to move it around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{code}
kmeans=: 3 :0
Nr=: $,smp
dis=: %: @ +/"1(initial -"1/ grid)^ 2
index=:(|:dis) i."1 (,.<./"1 (|:dis))
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{center}
  \fcolorbox{red!60!black}{white}{\BUseVerbatim{code}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}​
```

---

For formatting options, you should consider using the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).